# Why is Visual Studio trying to connect to my database when I only want to open my form1 designer?

Tags: c#, oledbconnection, visual-studio-2019

The problem I face is that for some reason, when I want to open my Form1.cs Designer, Visual Studio tries the execute the code of another .cs file "DataBase.cs" and it gives errors which prevent the designer to open properly.

EDIT : By searching inside the project, I saw that the `Form1.Designer.cs` has to run the `InitializeComponent` method which initialises the `usercontrol1`, which calls the `database.cs` code. So, the problem seems to be linked to the way user controls are integrated into the designer.
Is it a normal behavior or did I mess up something, for example by making some manipulations that added the `usercontrol1` to the `InitializeComponent` method when it normally should be called there?
Also, if it is a normal behavior, how can I avoid having the `Form1 Designer` call the database.cs ?

Here is the project tree :

[image]

The "Database.cs" includes these lines of code which initiate an OleDB connection using an .accdb Access file found by the app using a relative path:

`OleDbConnection connection;
connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source= ..\..\..\..\Kitbox.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
connection.Open();`

The thing is when Visual Studio runs this code to open the Form1.cs designer, it doesn't establish the connection properly and doesn't find the tables in my database which gives "not found" errors like this (while when running the application properly, it works) :

[image]

As a consequence, the datatable I fill later in the code can't be set and the dataview for the datatable can't be made which gives this error (traduction : Datatable must be defined before using Dataview) :

[image]

All of this prevents the designer to open properly.
So the main problem is : why does VS try to run the code in Database.cs when it's obviously useless because it runs it in a different way than the compiled application and fails ?
Any idea ?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you post the code in your `Form1.cs`? And maybe the one in your `Form1.Desigber.cs`.

Comment: It sounds like the constructor in Form1 is doing more than just initialising the form.  Is there some code in there that is calling you database connection code?

Comment: You answered your own title question: the designer is trying to connect to the database because as you said "Datatable must be defined before using Dataview")

Comment: But why does it have to do that to open the designer ?
Designing your app has to be done before it runs, why does VS try to run the app to be able to design it ?